# Windows command line, "python3" pointing to the wrong python3.exe

Tags: python, windows, environment-variables

So, I have Anaconda, OSGeo and Python2.7 installed on my computer.

I'm also using Spyder. In Spyder :

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\pythonw.exe'
```

Which is what I want.

However, in the windows command line and powershell :

```
$ python3
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
'C:\\Progra~1\\OSGeo4W\\bin\\python3.exe'
```

Which is **not** what I want. I want to use `'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\pythonw.exe'` (or `python.exe`, not sure) when using `python3` in the command line.

Also :

```
$ pip3
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'
```

I don't get why `python3` in the windows command line points to OSGeo's version of Python3. Here is my `path` :

```
C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Progra~1\OSGeo4W\bin\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\R Open\R-3.4.0\bin
```

I also have an environment variable called `PYTHONHOME`

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
```

---

Moreover (for completeness of information), I have python 2 installed :

```
$ python
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site.py", line 177
    file=sys.stderr)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

(`$ pip` outputs the same thing).

Having python3 and python2.7 both work when using `python3` and `python` (respectively) in the windows command line would be a nice bonus, but it's not really my priority.

Comment: Most distributions of Windows Python, including the official PSF distribution, do not include a "python3.exe" file. pip happens to install with "pip3" and "pip3.6", etc, because it's following a Unix convention. Windows Python in general does not follow that convention. At least one of the core developers for Windows Python vocally protests including "pythonX.exe" and "pythonX.Y.exe" files, and everyone else, as far as I can tell, pretty much doesn't care, so it's skewed against it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably several things you have to take care of:

In general the search order of the Windows PATH is from left to right starting with the system PATH. The first matching element wins. In your case this is correct because the system will search `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\` first. However in that folder is no executable called `python3` by default. On my system I created a simlink pointing to `python.exe`. On your system you can do it in PowerShell like this:

```
New-Item -Path C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python3.exe -ItemType SymbolicLink -Value C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe
```

`pip` is located in Scripts\ folder so in your case you have to add  `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts` to your `PATH` and create the corresponding simlinks again. In this case you have to create two of them because `pip.exe` is appending its name to the script that is trying to call (i.e. if your exe file is called `foo.exe` it will try to call `foo-script.exe` which does not exist) you can create the simlinks in PowerShell with those two commands:

```
New-Item -Path C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\pip3.exe -ItemType SymbolicLink -Value C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\pip.exe
```

and

```
New-Item -Path C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\pip3-script.py -ItemType SymbolicLink -Value C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\pip-script.py
```

Like this you will be able to use `python3` and `pip3` from your cmd line. Please check for similar problems with your python2 installation folder.

Hope it helps.